# I cant pass my array variable to another form in winform c#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I declared my array like this `string[] dateArray = new string[10];` then placing a value to it like this:

```
public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dateArray[i] = date.Text.ToString();
}
```

So far, after a few inputs and want to check if it the `dateArray` has a value I did this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dateArray);
 MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
}
```

And it is really have a value and displaying it. 
So I've created a button that may pass the value of `dateArray` to another form for it to display and print. I'm using iTextSharp. Here is my button:

```
  public static string finalDate;
  private void printBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string finalDate = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dateArray);
            printForm table_form = new printForm();
            table_form.Show();
        }
```

And passing the string `finalDate`(Second form) to here

```
 table2.AddCell(new Phrase(tableITS.finalDate, data));
```

But no luck, I tried putting a message box at the end of `doc.Close();` but it really doesn't have a value

```
 MessageBox.Show(tableITS.finalDate);
```

What am I getting wrong?
EDIT: 
I'm passing it here

```
private void printForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string finalDate2 = tableITS.finalDate;
.
.
.
//Document printing stuff
}
```

Comment: In which part of code you tried to pass an array to another form?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer

Comment: your question you mean ;)

Comment: I just want my value of `dateArray` to be cloned to the another form. But it is displaying blank.

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that You want to pass data from `Form1` to `Form2`:

Create a public property in `Form2`like:

```
public string[] dateArray { get; set;}
```

and then in your `Form1:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.dateArray = dateArray;
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Now you can use the `dateArray` in `Form2`

Comment: Is `ShowDialog()` just the same as `Show()`?

Comment: `ShowDialog()` shows the form and the opener form will be disabled till it closes and after closing you can get values from it. like: `Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.dateArray = dateArray;
frm.ShowDialog(); dateArray = frm.dateArray();`

Comment: I tried to use this method to my `string` but sad to say, the variable isn't passing through another form.

Comment: Ops sorry my bad, when I put it to the `Form3_Load` the messagebox show what I expected.